# Direct to new page inside middleware in Golang

Tags: go, go-templates

Let's say I have a button which will open a new page. This button's action is handled by an AJAX call to Golang API. This Golang API is wrapped by a middleware, `Verify`, which will verify everything before directing to that page. The page defined in the function passed into the middleware is using Golang HTML template.

```
router.GET("/newpage", Verify(newpageHandler))

func Verify(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        //verify everything here
        //if all verify, call newpageHandler to redirect to new page
        h.ServeHTTP(w,r)
    }
}

func newpageHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //this handler will process the html template
}
```

When I click the button (AJAX call to the `/newpage`), it doesn't open the new page, but only returns the HTML content from `newpageHandler` handler. I can see the HTML returned from the browser's developer tools, but it doesn't get that new page defined in `newpageHandler`.

Is it okay to use `http.Redirect`?

Answer (score 1):

AJAX calls will follow redirects implicitly. Alas, there is no way to prevent that. So, using `http.Redirect` is not a good option.

You could signal in your Verify func if the request was accepted or not. This can be easily done with http status codes. If everything was all right, you could return a 2xx code. In case of some error, you could return a 4xx code.

```
func Verify(h http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        //verify everything here. verifcationFunc() returns a bool
        if verifcationFunc() {
          w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        } else {
          w.WriteHeader(http.StatusUnauthorized)
        }
    }
}
```

You can now evaluate the returned status code in your JavaScript. On a 200 you can set the new location in JavaScript. This can be done with `window.location`. On a 401 code (in the example above) you can output an error message.

Comment: What should I do with the handler I passed into the middleware `h http.HandlerFunc` ?, the handler do nothing inside middleware?

Comment: It depends. If the new URL is dynamic, `newpageHandler` could render a json result with the new url. The javascript would have to evaluate that result and dynamically set the location to the received URL. If the URL is static, the javascript could already know about the URL. Then the `newpageHandler` func won't be needed any more.

Comment: How to pass data from the `Verify` to the template handler?, I have many data that need to be passed from the `Verify` middleware to the new page, I should not pass the data through the url params in `windows.location` since the data should not be shown.

Comment: The ideal situation would be, that you do not need to pass data to the handler. The verification could be independent from the actual handler. A general verification (a middleware should be general) should only verify and not mutate any state. If you really have to pass data you can use the request's context. You can add data to the context and read it in the handler. In this way, you do not have to change the handler's signature. There is an official blog post: https://blog.golang.org/context A word of warning though. Use the context sparingly and only if it makes sense globally.

Comment: For what use cases do you want to pass data to the handler?

Comment: So, before opening that new page, I need to verify some. If verification return error or false, it will return json with error message to ajax call and opening the new page won't happen. If the verification pass, the result is data that need to be passed to the html templates and new page open with the data being passed inside the new page.

Comment: This is correct for the error case. For your success case: It depends. If you do client side rendering, then you are correct. You could pass the new URL as JSON and set window.location in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you will to change the page, then AJAX isn't what you want. Instead of sending an AJAX request to the API, you should redirect the browser to that API using one of the following methods for example:

HTML :

```
<a href="url/to/my/api">Go To page</a>
```

Javascript:

```
window.location = "url/to/my/api"
```

Comment: If I use link, How to handle error returned as json from the `Verify` middleware?. If it return error, page will be redirected to blank page with only json response on it.